# How can I diagnose a persistent whole-system freeze on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, lockup

I am running an HP Spectre 360 x2. I originally set up with Ubuntu 15.10 on it and ran perfectly for months.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 several days after the official release. Since then, my computer hard locks multiple times per day. I frequently get to a state in which the system becomes completely unresponsive, none of the fans are spinning. In this state, even ctrl-alt-f2 does not work. If I happened to be playing music at this moment, the music gets trapped in a very short loop (quarter of a second?). At this point, the only thing I can do is to power cycle the machine.

Log files show nothing helpful, but do show a string of NULL characters right at the time the system locks. The problem is completely unpredictable. I have been unable to associate the problem with the presence or absence of any particular piece of hardware, to music or lack of music, or any computer network, though it does seem to happen much more frequently on my work network than on my home network.

By contrast, I have an older System76 laptop at home, also running 16.04, that has no problems.

Here's a listing of the hardware in the system:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 50)
```

At this point, I have no idea what else I can add to try diagnosing the problem, so I am looking for advice.

Comment: If you boot your laptop to a Live CD/USB does it do the same thing?